# Why a differentiator is unstable from pole zeros view point?

Tags: fourier-transform, control-systems, poles-zeros

A differentiator with frequency response $j2 \pi f$ is unstable because as frequency increases its response becomes out of bound.

But from a pole zero point of view a differentiator just have zeros and no pole, so I believe it is a FIR filter, but then it should be stable [see this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/50549/bibo-stability-for-system-with-no-poles)

I am confused how one can talk about the stability of a differentiator and integrator from pole and zeros point of view. Can any body help?

Comment: A digital differentiator that's causal ***does*** have a pole.  At $z=0$.

Comment: Integrators are *"marginally stable"* or *"critically stable"* because the pole lies on the unit circle at $z=1$.  There is something we call a *"leaky integrator"* that's stable because it's pole is just inside the unit circle.  But it leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may confusing a continuous and a discrete differentiator. A continuous differentiator has indeed a transfer function $H(\omega) = j\cdot \omega$ but FIR implies a time discrete filter.

Discretizing a differentiator is difficult. The transfer function is NOT bandlimited. In fact, it's almost the opposite: it gets worse the higher the frequency becomes. That means you can't sample without significant amount of aliasing.

There are various approximations, the simplest one being $h_d= [1,-1]$. This has a pole at $z = 0$ and a zero at $z = 1$, so it's perfectly stable. The transfer function is

$$H_d(\omega) = 1 - e^{-j\omega} = e^{-j\omega/2} \cdot (e^{j\omega/2}- e^{-j\omega/2}) =  e^{-j\omega/2} \cdot 2j \sin(\omega/2) $$

For $ \omega \ll 1$ this becomes

$$ H_d(\omega) \approx e^{-j\omega/2} \cdot j\omega $$

So for low frequencies this does look a differentiator cascaded with a half-sample delay. That delay is caused by the fact that the impulse response is not centered around n=0 but (more or less) n = 0.5.

However, at the Nyquist frequency ($\omega = \pi$)the magnitude error is substantial. It's $|H_d(\pi) = 2|$ as compared to $\pi$ for a continuous differentiator.

> I am confused how one can talk about the stability of a differentiator and integrator from pole and zeros point of view.

If you are referring to poles and zeros in the Z-plane, you have implied discretization. That involves either aggressive low pass filtering or substantial aliasing. Either (or both) of these will ensure stability.

Answer (score 3):

There are two cases to consider. In *continuous time*, an ideal differentiator has the transfer function

$$H(s)=s\tag{1}$$

This transfer function has one zero at $s=0$ and one pole at $s=\infty$. Hence, the ideal continuous time differentiator is unstable.

In *discrete time*, we have to ask ourselves what we mean by an ideal differentiator. In analogy with the continuous-time case, we define the frequency response of an ideal discrete-time differentiator by

$$H(\omega)=j\omega,\qquad \omega\in(-\pi,\pi]\tag{2}$$

The impulse response corresponding to $(2)$ is

$$h[n]=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{(-1)^n}{n},& n\neq 0\\0,& n=0\end{cases}\tag{3}$$

The ideal discrete-time differentiator defined by $(2)$ and $(3)$ doesn't have a transfer function because the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $(3)$ doesn't exist. Consequently, we can't talk about poles and zeros in this case. Note that there are several other ideal systems for which the same is true: ideal frequency-selective filters (lowpass, highpass, etc.), or the ideal Hilbert transformer.

The ideal discrete-time differentiator is unstable because its impulse response is not absolutely summable, i.e.,

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left|h[n]\right|=\infty$$

In sum, we can't always use poles to determine a system's stability because some ideal systems do not have transfer functions, or they might have transfer functions that are not rational (such as an ideal delay in continuous time). In such cases we must use the impulse response in order to determine if the system is stable.

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/pasp/Digital_Differentiator_Design.html). As you said, an FIR implementation has no issues with stability, but it's actual performance near Nyquist tends to struggle, particularly for low filter order. To better overcome this, some implementations incorporate poles to improve the higher frequency performance, though this comes with the cost of potential instability.